# Delete row in tsv file if the value in the second column is a 1

Tags: excel, csv, filter

I have a tsv file that's structured like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  122363
ATGCTGTATAGAATATAT  1
CAGCTCACTTAAACTTAA  1
GTCTGACATCTTACATGA  3
TGCCTTAACTTGTTATTA  1
GTGTTTGATGTCGTTGTC  1
TTAAAAAAATTTTGCCTT  9
GTCCTATAAGGCTTCCCT  1
CGGGTTGGGAAGCACACA  1
TTTTTTAGACGAAAACTA  30
GACTCCTGGTCACGTAAG  12
TGGTTTTTGTTTTGTAAT  58
TGTATAATGGACGTCGCA  1
```

And I want to find every instance of a "1" in the right column and delete the entire row so the final data set looks like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  122363
GTCTGACATCTTACATGA  3
TTAAAAAAATTTTGCCTT  9
TTTTTTAGACGAAAACTA  30
GACTCCTGGTCACGTAAG  12
TGGTTTTTGTTTTGTAAT  58
```

I have been able to go into Excel and filter the two columns to only show instances of "1" in the right column and tried to select all the rows and delete them in one go. However, this file is ~2 Gb so the amount of data is pretty large for the Excel grid and the command to delete the selected rows hangs for a while before it crashes.

To work around this, I want to use a bash command/python script instead. Does anyone know of something quick and easy I can use to search for instances in the right column that equal 1 and delete both it and the data in the left column?

Comment: I believe you could do this with `Power Query`, open a new excel file, and click on **`Data`** Tab --> **`Get Data`** --> **`From File`** --> **`From Excel Workbook`**. And then when the PQ editor opens do the cleaning & transformations you need.

Comment: Question title and tags do not indicate that you're targetting bash

Answer (score 3):

I decided to hard code what I wanted to do and then quickly realized it had a pretty simple solution in Python:

```py
import csv

kmercount = "originalFile.tsv"
kmerout = "cleanFile.tsv"

with open(kmercount, "r") as file, open(kmerout, "w") as out:
    read = csv.reader(file, delimiter = "\t")
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter = "\t")

    for row in read:
        if row[1] != "1":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

This reads in the original file and writes out all the rows that do not contain only "1" in the right column to a separate file. I think there's an even simpler solution if you use the `pandas` package but this worked for me. If anyone has a problem like this use this script!

Comment: Good, you resolved it on your own, also ensure to accept the answer so it will others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

grep can quickly exclude lines ending in 1...

```
grep -v " 1$" file.tsv > filteredFile.tsv
```

More complex files might have multiple columns and values, but yours should work with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks fairly simple: a column, a tab, and a final column.  You want to suppress rows with a 1 in column two (the final column).

You can use grep to match on lines that have a tab (`\t`) followed by a 1 followed by an end-of-line (`$`), then invert the match (with -v):

```
grep -v '\t1$' input.tsv
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  122363
GTCTGACATCTTACATGA  3
TTAAAAAAATTTTGCCTT  9
TTTTTTAGACGAAAACTA  30
GACTCCTGGTCACGTAAG  12
TGGTTTTTGTTTTGTAAT  58
```

If you need to consistently manipulate CSV/TSV from the command line, I recommend a legit CSV tool like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/).  I really don't like csvkit for all the options it has that either overwrite other options or just don't seem to work; it's also in Python so if the datasets are big you can suffer some performance penalties compared to something like GoCSV.  GoCSV, for my taste, really gets the UNIX philosophy of many small tools that excel at doing one thing—and one thing only.

GoCSV commands assumes a header row, so you'll have to add one (just for processing):

```
export GOCSV_DELIMITER="\t"
gocsv cap --default-name Col input.tsv
Col 1   Col 2
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  122363
ATGCTGTATAGAATATAT  1
CAGCTCACTTAAACTTAA  1
GTCTGACATCTTACATGA  3
TGCCTTAACTTGTTATTA  1
GTGTTTGATGTCGTTGTC  1
TTAAAAAAATTTTGCCTT  9
GTCCTATAAGGCTTCCCT  1
CGGGTTGGGAAGCACACA  1
TTTTTTAGACGAAAACTA  30
GACTCCTGGTCACGTAAG  12
TGGTTTTTGTTTTGTAAT  58
TGTATAATGGACGTCGCA  1
```

Then pipe that into filter, then behead (to get rid of the intermediate header):

```
gocsv cap --default-name Col input.tsv | gocsv filter -c 'Col 2' -eq 1 -exclude | gocsv behead
```

Like grep, the results are streamed (in the pipeline) so the memory overhead is neglible.